# ssh-like client authentication with Netty

Tags: ssl, netty, pki

I'm trying to establish a secure socket between clients and a server that is written with Netty (it's really just a TCP socket, no standard higher-level protocol like HTTP, etc.).

I'm aware of the two-way SSL implementation pattern for Netty, but I actually need something slightly simpler, more similar to password-less ssh authentication (I think). For example, to securely connect via ssh to a server, I can generate a key pair on the client and then add my public key to the server's .ssh/authorized_keys file; notably, a client doesn't need to transmit an actual certificate, just a public key.

I'd like to implement a similar mechanism with Netty, but I'm a little stumped how to (a) transmit the public key from the client, and (b) retrieve that key from the server's SSL session so that I can verify it against a list of known keys. For (a), I'm currently using openssl's -key option, which may or may not be the right thing here. For (b), I'm not sure how to proceed at all, since all the mechanisms that Netty supports by default seem to require a certificate, not just a public key.

Comment: On doing some further research, it looks like RFC 7250 is something that would fit the bill here. However, this particular TLS extension does not appear to be widely supported at this point (I would need a Netty implementation on the back end, and, ideally, the openssl command line tool should work on the client, neither of which seems to be supported at the moment).